# Adding Geometry objects data wpf

Tags: wpf, geometry

Just wondering if this is possible in wpf,
Say we have a Path object p1 with geometry = g1 (same as p1.Data).
Similarly if we have another Path object p2 with geometry = g2 (same as p2.Data).
Now if we would like to know what is g2-g1 (same as p2.Data - p1.Data) is it possible.
How about g1+g2?
Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [CombinedGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry.aspx) object, which I'm doing to make a single mask out of shapes drawn with the [DrawTools library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DrawTools.aspx).

```
var added = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Union, g2, g1);
var subtracted = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Exclude, g2, g1);
```